# How to find a string is present in array of strings in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which captures responses from a Google Form where user can select multiple options from pre-defined options. For an example, say question is which days do you work? and options are {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"} and user can either select only 1 or multiple.

> User 1: "Sunday","Tuesday","Wednesday"
>
> User 2: "Monday","Friday","Saturday"
>
> User 3: "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"
>
> User 4: "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"

And I want to find the list of Users who are working on say "Tuesday". In response Spreadsheet, all the above responses for each users are saved in single column (for example column E) like:

> E1: Sunday,Tuesday,Wednesday
>
> E2: Monday,Friday,Saturday
>
> E3: Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday
>
> E4: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday

and user names are also in a single column (say in Column B)

> B1: User 1
>
> B2: User 2
>
> B3: User 3
>
> B4: User 4

Now I want to use something similar to Filter() where array is filtered and displayed (like B1:B) where *E1:E contains "Tuesday"*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
=query('Responses'!A:E, "Select B where E contains 'Tuesday'", 1)
```

Change sheet name and range to suit.